# The invoice number is characters and numbers combined but I want to change these to numerical only in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The invoice number is characters and numbers combined but I want to change these to numerical only in SQL.

I want like this CC/DDD/1, CC/DDD/2 .... n

[image: column_image]

Comment: Does the prefix is absolutely the same in all records? If not - does its length is absolutely the same in all records?

Comment: Please check [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) as to why screenshots are a bad idea on StackExchange. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: How are you planning on keeping the invoice id unique? Do you only have invoices for 2018-2019 -  will the date be part of it? Do you have any restrictions on the size of the number you use?

Comment: Please give us the invoice ids you have now - is that what the image is? And then show us how you'd like to transform invoice with id = X into a number?

Comment: Just from a non-database point of view - has that invoice number been put on any documents that customers have seen?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, I did the following (all of the steps shown below are in the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e97c1a0cc02adf641a88a7bafb5e5a24)).

## First part - if you wish to keep the old invoice numbers:

Construct and populate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice 
(
  invoice_id VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO invoice 
VALUES
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/3'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/6'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/7'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/9'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/12'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/23'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/27'),
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/122222'),  -- The large numbers are for testing of sorting,
('CC/DDD/2018-2019/244444');  -- thanks to @DougDeden for pointing out problems in this area
```

I'll step through the logic I used.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(invoice_id)) AS cutoff FROM invoice;
```

Result:

```
cutoff
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
7
7
```

Get the [`REVERSE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_reverse.asp) of the string along with the [`CHARINDEX`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp) of `/` and then obtain the position of the first slash (`/`) which tells us where the number of interest lies.

Then, I ran:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1) AS the_num
FROM invoice;
```

Result:

```
the_num
3
6
7
9
21
32
72
222221
444442 -- note original is 24444
```

The [`LEFT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142387/470530) function gives us the actual number to be suffixed (added) to the invoice.

Finally, I ran:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(invoice_id, 1, 7) 
        + REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), 
          CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS new_invoice_id
FROM invoice
ORDER BY -- CAST(new_invoice_id AS INTEGER);  -- try this more elegant but it doesn't work!
  CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', 
                    REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS INTEGER);
```

Result:

```
new_invoice_id
CC/DDD/3
CC/DDD/6
CC/DDD/7
CC/DDD/9
CC/DDD/12
CC/DDD/23
CC/DDD/27
CC/DDD/122222
CC/DDD/244444
```

Note that in order to obtain the correct result, it is necessary to `REVERSE` **back** the original one, not very elegant, but these functions are quite performant. Thanks to @DougDeden for pointing out an error in the original answer!

As mentioned above, all of this is in the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e97c1a0cc02adf641a88a7bafb5e5a24).

## Second part - if you wish to renumber the invoices:

@Lennart proposes a simultaneous renumbering, so for completeness, I'm adding a similar solution to my answer. The first steps are the same as above - the SQL does become a bit cumbersome, but it can be done as follows - first, to obtain the new numbers:

```
SELECT 
  REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS the_num,
  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS INTEGER))
    AS new_number
FROM invoice
ORDER BY 
  CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', 
            REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS INTEGER);
```

Result:

```
the_num new_number
3       1
6       2
7       3
9       4
12      5
23      6
27      7
122222  8
244444  9
```

Be **very** careful when sorting - if you sort `INTEGER`s as `VARCHAR`s, the results are anomalous - basically, sorting `INT`s as strings means that the "numbers" are sorted by the first digit, so 32, 332 and 45 will sort as 32, 332 and 45 and not 32, 45, 332.

So, now we have our renumbering - a final step is necessary:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(invoice_id, 1, 7) +
  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', 
                        REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS INTEGER)) AS VARCHAR)
  AS invoice_no
FROM invoice
ORDER BY 
  CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(invoice_id), CHARINDEX('/', 
           REVERSE(invoice_id)) - 1)) AS INTEGER);
```

Notice the [`CAST`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp) of the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) - if this is not done, an error is thrown `Msg 8114 Level 16 State 5 Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to bigint`. You can't "add" an `INTEGER` to a string!

Result:

```
invoice_no
CC/DDD/1
CC/DDD/2
CC/DDD/3
CC/DDD/4
CC/DDD/5
CC/DDD/6
CC/DDD/7
CC/DDD/8
CC/DDD/9
```

As mentioned in the comments, this renumbering is **probably** not a good idea as it will require the maintenance of a correspondance between the old invoice numbers and the new invoice numbers. All of these steps above are shown in the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e97c1a0cc02adf641a88a7bafb5e5a24).

Comment: Thanks @DougDeden for pointing out that schoolboy error - corrected!